# Base64 to binary data python

Tags: image, base64, communication, binary-data

I'm trying to convert a base64 string to binary data using this code:

```
output = base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_url).content)
bin = "".join(format(ord(x), "b") for x in base64.decodestring(output))
```

while I'm trying to convert `bin` (the binary data) into base64 using this code:

```
codecs.encode(bin, 'base64')
```

I get a different string than the original one.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What language is this? You should add the tag for the language.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Methinks "python"... *"requests"* gave it away 